# WP_Query - display posts by custom field and order by another

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

I have custom WP_Query call where I want to display CPT by one custom field and order them by another:

```
   $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'nehnutelnost',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_key' => 'podlazie',
        'meta_value' => '2_nadzemne_podlazie',
        'meta_compare' => 'LIKE',
        'meta_key' => 'cislo_bytu',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',

    );
    
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'state_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => 'Wisconsin',
        ),
        'city_clause' => array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 
        'city_clause' => 'ASC',
        'state_clause' => 'DESC',
    ),
) );
```

You can use this query for ordering, even with more than one meta keys. These are called sub queries.

Please check this link from codex -
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/